# How to set the background of UINavigationBar in Objective-C ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the `background` of `UINavigationBar`.

I already put the image to `Images.xcassets` , and the `xib` file is `TableView`

[image]

I have write `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` in the `viewDidLoad` like the following.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

        //self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"WiFi Camera Viewer", nil) ;
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

But the `UINavigationBar` did not show any image like the following [image]

**How to set the background of UINavigationBar in Objective-C ?**

Did I missing something ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that do you have image named "bar-background.png"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are using is old, starting from iOS 7 you could use the below

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you provide an image with 44px height, it'll cover the navigation bar only without the status bar, if you provide it with 66px height, it'll cover them both